# Is disclosure of subprocessors absolutely necessary under the GDPR?

Tags: european-union, gdpr

Under the GDPR regulations, is there a way of avoiding the need to disclose the full names and details of subprocessors?

Must I absolutely declare this information in the appropriate manner or can I limit the amount of this information I reveal?

Comment: To whom are you declaring? And, are you a processor contracting with a sub processor or are you a controller or another party?

Comment: Possible duplicate/overlap - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17918/resellers-under-gdpr-disclosure-of-data-processors-or-countries-of-data-storag